# Python django non-nullable field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default="")
    price = models.ImageField(default=0)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default="")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="shop/images", default="")
```

And I'm getting the line below. I don't know whether it is warning or error:
You are trying to add a non-nullable field '**pub_date**' to the product without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

What does it mean actually ??

Comment: What is not clear about the error message?

Comment: It tells me - (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already constructed migrations where you create the table for the `Product` table. It is thus possible that there are already *records* for that table.

Now you are adding a new column, this thus means you need to fill the column for the *existing* records. You did not specify a [**`default=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default), hence Django can not use this as a value.

For a field with [**`null=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) without a default value, by default it will use `None`/`NULL` as value, but here your `pub_date` is not a nullable field.

This thus means that Django does not know what to do here. Normally Django will propose two solutions:

> ```
>  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
> ```

## First option

You thus select the first option by writing <kbd>1</kbd> (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>), then you can enter an expression that specifies what to use as default, for example `timezone.now` as the default for the *existing* records, not the new records:

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> timezone.now  # Enter
```

## Second option

If you select <kbd>2</kbd> (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>), Django will stop creating the migration file, and give you the opportunity to specify a default yourself in the `models.py`: this will then be used for all *existing* and *new* records. For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    # …
```

You can also use [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to automatically use the current date as value, and make the field non-editable:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    # …
```